# How can i limit a user to use no more ram than 1gb in window 2012 r2 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, memory, vps, users

is it possible to to limit a user ram?
No more ram than 1gb in window 2012 r2 server?

One of of my user is using about 3GB ram

Answer (score 0):

With standard build in tools that's not possible really. You need to look for third party tools TScale for example. Unless it's more relating to process usage then you can limit that using Windows System Resource Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use remote app to lock the user on only the application he need access to or use policy to block app he can access.

If the problem is the application that he use need 3 gig of ram then by definition you cant limit him, as the application will crash...